# When can upgrades be obtained or edited?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

The rules say "Once runners have earned Karma, they may gain upgrades." on page 22 of the rules.  Does this mean that I specifically may not change my upgrades after a mission in which I've failed to gain any Karma, and also that anytime I gain even a single Karma point, I can manage my upgrades?  It seems to make more sense, even more so since they are able to be swapped out, to be allowed to switch them between any missions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're reading this too literally.
"Once runners have earned Karma..." is just an answer to "When do I start buying upgrades, in general?"

For each runner, their earned Karma is a permanent value.
If you earn 3 Karma from completing a mission, that's 3 Karma that this runner will always have. This runner "has earned karma", now and forevermore.
Each runner is always "worth" as much karma as he has ever earned.

Between missions, each runner can "spend" their karma to buy or swap abilities on their sheet (by the costing rules).  *(the term "spend" isn't exactly right either; your karma is just your maximum capacity for upgrades, but it never goes away)*
Even if they didn't gain any new karma on that specific mission.